# Pairing up elements of sublists within lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists `Ci,Cb`.

I am pairing up each element of the sublists within the lists. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
Ci=[[0, 0],[1, 2]]
Cb=[[0.1, 0.1],[5, 6]]
C1=[]
t=2
for j in range(t):
    for i in range(2):
        C=[Ci[j][i],Cb[j][i]]
        C1.append(C)
print(C1)
```

The current output is:

```
[[0, 0.1], [0, 0.1], [1, 5], [2, 6]]
```

The expected output is:

```
[[[0, 0.1], [0, 0.1]], [[1, 5], [2, 6]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired output using `zip()`,

Link to zip doc:   [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
[list(zip(Ci[x],Cb[x])) for x,y in enumerate(Ci)]
#[[(0, 0.1), (0, 0.1)], [(1, 5), (2, 6)]]

[list(list(x) for x in zip(Ci[x],Cb[x])) for x,y in enumerate(Ci)]
#[[[0, 0.1], [0, 0.1]], [[1, 5], [2, 6]]]
```